# How to mock Mono.from(commandResult).block();

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, reactive-programming

I have a class that invokes mongodb using reactive library and am writing a unit test that includes this private method. How to mock `Mono.from(commandResult).block()` using mockito?

```
private Document runCommand(final String command) {
        final MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("admin");
        final Bson bsonDocument = Document.parse(command).toBsonDocument();
        final Publisher<Document> commandResult = db.runCommand(bsonDocument);
        return Mono.from(commandResult).block();
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to mock/replace `runCommand` or the static `from` method?

Comment: Just mock mongoClient, db and commandResult, with appropriate `when`s.

Comment: mocking the db client actually worked!

Answer (score 0):

Retuning Mono.just() worked

```
@Test
    void initializeDBTest() {
        final Document bsonDoc = Document.parse(isCSResponse);
        Mockito.when(mongoClient.getDatabase("admin")).thenReturn(db);
        Mockito.when(db.runCommand(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(Mono.just(bsonDoc));
        manageDB.initializeDB();
    }
```